# Is an excessively shy person a "gussie"?

Tags: expressions, idioms, slang

I'm sure most of us are familiar with a shrinking violet as being an excessively shy person; however, while reading from *Flappers to Rappers: History of American Youth Slang* Dr. Dalzell defines a "gussie" as 1920s slang for an excessively shy individual. Any ideas why this may be?

Comment: I can see that you don’t know [Gussie Fink-Nottle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gussie_Fink-Nottle) in particular — not to mention [Gussie Mannering-Phipps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extricating_Young_Gussie) — or you wouldn’t even ask. :)  Fink-Nottle is “[d]escribed as "a teetotal bachelor with a face like a fish", he wears horn-rimmed spectacles and is a noted newt fancier.”

Comment: Wow, "all gussied up" http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-gus1.htm looks to be a 1960's thing: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+gussied+up&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%20gussied%20up%3B%2Cc0 I had no idea!

Answer (score 1):

[Both the OED and Professor Jonathan Lighter (in the Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang) point tentatively to an earlier use of Gussy or Gussie as a term for an effeminate or weak person. This appeared in the US at the end of the nineteenth century.](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-gus1.htm)

[An interesting discussion here](http://wordsmith.org/board/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=109021&page=1)